# Any Simulatore available for BLE devices

Tags: ios7, ios8, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios-bluetooth

Is there any BLE simulator  available ?
Apart from that also want to know how can I send commands from BLE device to iOS and wake my iOS app  if iPhone  is already paired with the iOS

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The LightBlue app on the app store can act as several different types of common BLE peripherals.  For the second part of your question, I suggest you read the Core Bluetooth programming guide and the section on background operation in particular

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 for the help ,Will update the status here one i achieved :)